# Oracle: Format string for a IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle

In a varchar2 field (table1.field1), I have something like this:
;number1;number2;.......;numberN;

I want use this value in a IN statement, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.field2 IN table1.field1
```

Comment: Question is not clear.. what do you want to do with number1, number2.. and what is table1.field1

Comment: You'll have to apply regex to get numbers from this string.

Comment: In Field1 of Table1 is stored a varchar2 string like this: ";number1;number2;.....;numberN;" where number1,number2,....numberN are numbers. I want to make a select from Table2 filtered by the number in Table1.Field1. Something like:
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.FIELD2 IN (numbers in my TABLE1.FIELD1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values of table2.field2 are strings like 
number1
number2

Then Try this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
 WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
          FROM table1
         WHERE table1.field1 LIKE '%;' || table2.field2 || ';%'
    )
```

If the table2 are similar to what you have in table1.field1 then try this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table2 
 WHERE field2 IN 
    (
        SELECT field1
          FROM table1
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Chandu, the first solution is what I need!